# .NET Framework Change

Tags: .net, frameworks

I Have an issue with changing target framework. I have a project with target framework 4.0 and I changed it to 4.5 to use some 4.5 features. Then I reload the project and cleaned it then ı rebuild the project but the features of 4.5 is not working properly.

Comment: define "an issue" and "is not working properly" - we're going to need more than that to be able to help you; also - .NET 4.5 was "end of life" around January 2016 - so you're switching to something that has been dead for over 4.5 years - you *might* want to consider moving to something more recent/supportable instead (net472/net48 for .NET Framework, or - and preferably - .NET Core 3.1 or similar)

Comment: It's same with other frameworks. I have an program which gets a program's modules. It's not working with .net 4.0 so ı decided to change my framework to 4.5, the result is same with 4.0 and it doesn't show all the modules only specific ones. But ı created a new application with framework 4.5 it shows all the modules correct.

Comment: OK, so to rephrase: you have some code that is *meant* to list modules, but it only shows *some* of the modules; and it does this in both 4.0 and 4.5 (with no real difference between them), and what you actually want is: to show all the modules. Well, perhaps what would be useful, then, is to show the code you're using to list the modules, *and* to say which ones it isn't showing - there may be *reasons* that they aren't showing: for example, perhaps they haven't been loaded yet; also, it would be interesting to know why you expected 4.5 to work differently to 4.0 on this

Comment: This is the result with .net 4.5: https://prnt.sc/u62qv9 And this is the result with .net 4.0 same code: https://prnt.sc/u62rcl The code is: https://prnt.sc/u62roz

Comment: I think that's an interesting difference

Comment: I want to go for 4.5 or something higher but changing framework version is not working for me and if I create a new application with 4.5 and change it to 4.0 then 4.5 it doesn't work properly it shows like 4.0 I know it's weird but it's a real problem for me. I have to change it to 4.5 or something higher.

Comment: So something is different between your *new* 4.5 app, and the app that you've migrated from 4.0 to 4.5; a good place to start would be comparing the csproj of those two projects, to look for any differences - and poke those differences with a stick. The "CPU Mode" (x86/x64/Any) would be of particular interest to me.

Comment: I changed the platfrom target to x86 from any and it actually worked. But I don't know what is the difference beetween any and x86 ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, it sounds like the fundamental problem here was the CPU platform target; essentially there are four possible targets:

- always run in x86 mode (32-bit mode)
- always run in x64 mode (64-bit mode; obviously this won't work on 32-bit OSes or devices, but you don't see many of those any more!)
- run in either x86 or x64 but prefer x64 when possible
- run in either x86 or x64 but prefer x86 when possible

It sounds like you are targeting an external 32-bit process, and your tool application was running as a 64-bit process. Windows has a lot of smoke and mirrors between 32-bit and 64-bit processes (hence the existence of "WOW64" - aka "Windows 32-bit on Windows 64-bit", etc). For best results when looking between different processes, 32-bit tools should look at 32-bit processes, and 64-bit tools should look at 64-bit processes. Since gta_sa seems to be 32-bit, a 32-bit tool will have better results querying that API, as it isn't just looking at the WOW64 shim, but can look directly at the real process.